# Will javascript execute which is in an HREF?

Tags: xss

I have located an issue where the user can provide an HTML that will be rendered on a page. Unfortunately, the HTML is rendered inside an `href` attribute using `"`(quotes), making it impossible to exploit such scenarios as:

```
<a href=https://google.com onClick=alert(1)> https://google.com </a>
```

In order for the link to be rendered it has to fulfill the following regex: `` (https?:\/\/[^"<>\\^`{|}\s]+[^"<>\\^`{|}\s.,:;!?]) ``. In other words, it must start with `http` or `https` and it will stop as soon as it encounters a disallowed character (`` [^"<>\\^`{|}\s]+ ``), making it impossible to exploit the scenario using:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(1)"> javascript:alert(1) </a>
```

Is there any browser (including older ones) that will execute any javascript is followed by a `https://` in an `href` attribute?

Comment: I think that the regex you have provided is missing `^` in the beginning, so `javascript:alert(1)//https://example.com` would still work.